# How to update taxonomy on user profile from a view

Tags: 7, views, users, rules

I have an interesting issue and hope for advice on the best solution in Drupal 7.

I have a taxonomy that exists for events and also in the User Profile. The basic functionality I need is when the user clicks on button or link in a list of events, created by a view the taxonomy terms of type category are taken and added to the taxonomy term field (also of type category) In this way the user's profile gets updated with the taxonomy terms from the event. In this way the profile gains the preferences of the user.

I have the view set up so a link is my-view/term1,term2,term3

But how to get that exposed either to rules so I can loggedInUser - Set Value, I cannot see or find out how to link the two parts.

I have looked at Rules Links but the documentation seems lacking. I need this entirely reusable as the mechanism will be reused in two more use cases.

Has anyone any suggestions?

Or do I have to write a module

Comment: Hi

You know how if you don't use a module for years (literally) you forget about it. Well when I looked at my question above I spotted flag underneath. I hadn't used this since I built a social network in Drupal in 2011 and one of those lightbulb moments happened. So I am running with that. Hopefully I can trigger a rule using flag and get further than I did.

Still open to better solutions or advice on this approach too.